# Delivery Confirmation For Sent Mail

Tags: java, notifications, smtp, jakarta-mail

My requirement is to send E-Mail Alerts to various customers for our client for which, we're planning to use JavaMail API. However, once mail is sent, we need to update status in DB as Sent/Delivered/Failure depending on the status of the mail. Please tell me how do we get Delivery Notification for the **mail reaching the Mail Server of the Receiver**. It's not necessary to ensure whether the person has read the mail or not, however, it will be great if we'll be able to know that. The mandatory thing to check is for delivery. How can we get the status. What I read was that using 'SMTPMessage' we can get the status, however, I couldn't find a code sample for how to read the Notification. I am putting my code which is very sample of what I have done till now. Please let me know how I can achieve the thing which we are trying to fulfill.

```
public class MailSender {
    private int port = 25;
    private String host = "testmailsrvr";
    private String from = "test@test.com";
    private boolean auth = true;
    private String username = "test";
    private String password = "test@123";
    private Protocol protocol = Protocol.SMTP;
    private boolean debug = true;


    public void sendEmail(String strMailID, String strSubject, String strBody) throws MessagingException{
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", port);
        switch (protocol) {
        case SMTPS:
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", true);
            break;
        case TLS:
            props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", true);
            break;
        case SMTP:
            props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", false);
            break;
        }

        Authenticator authenticator = null;
        if (auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", true);
            authenticator = new Authenticator() {
                private PasswordAuthentication pa = new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                @Override
                public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return pa;
                }
            };
        }

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, authenticator);
        session.setDebug(debug);

        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));

        InternetAddress[] toAddress = {new InternetAddress(strMailID)};
        message.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAddress);

        message.setSubject(strSubject);
        message.setSentDate(new Date());

        message.setText(strBody);
        Transport.send(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to read these JavaMail FAQ entries:

- [If I send a message to a bad address, why don't I get a SendFailedException or TransportEvent indicating that the address is bad?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#badaddr)
- [When a message can't be delivered, a failure message is returned. How can I detect these "bounced" messages?](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#bounce)

Then read the javadocs for the [com.sun.mail.smtp](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/smtp/package-summary.html) and [com.sun.mail.dsn](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/dsn/package-summary.html) packages to learn about Delivery Status Notifications.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to approach the issue differently. The Transport.send() method will throw a SendFailedException if it runs into problems sending to any of the recipients. The exception will give you information on which recipient addresses failed. You should catch that exception, get the failing addresses and record them.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into http://www.ultrasmtp.com.  This service will send a notice back to the recipient upon the message being accepted, deferred, or refused by the receiving mail server.  There is also an option to setup alerts for opened messages.